# Potentiometer related question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

Sorry, I am posting a assignment question but I found no other option.

Figure shows a potentiometer circuit for comparison of two resistances. The balance point with a standard resistor R=10.0Ω is found to be 58.3 cm, while that with the unknown resistance X is 68.5 cm. Determine the value of X.

[image: Circuit diagram of potentiometer]

$l_1$ and $l_2$ refer to balance points potentiometer wire, that is 58.3cm and 68.5 cm respectively.

I fail to understand why $l_1$ and $l_2$ should be different. Isn't potentiometer connect to the same cell?

The solution given in my book seems to be wrong-
[image: The solution given in my book seems to be wrong]

Comment: What are $l_1$ and $l_2$ supposed to be here?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic  $l_1$ and $l_2$ refer to length of potentiometer wire, that is 58.3cm and 68.5 cm respectively.

Comment: This post asks a point about potentiometer which is a doubt of many high school students. Please don't close it just because it began with a homework question.

Comment: 1. What are the `()` in the diagram? Switches? 2. I don't understand where $l_1$ and $l_2$ here come from, or why you think they are the "length of potentiometer  wire", when the question talks about two different *balance points*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind oh I am sorry. I got confused by terminologies. Yes, you are right. I meant balance point. Extremely sorry. Also ( ) refer to switches which are closed one at a time.

Comment: You can edit your question to clear that up - and maybe explain a bit more what about the two different balance points confuses you

Answer (score 1):

(a) The cell labelled 'E' will have an internal resistance. If *X* has a higher resistance than 10 $ \Omega$ then there will be less current in the lower circuit and a smaller pd across the internal resistance, leaving a greater pd across *X*.

(b) Unless I am being more than usually silly, there isn't enough information in the question to find a numerical value for $X$.

Comment: Hey man, I do have solution at the back of my book but it seems wrong. That is why I asked it here.

Comment: Can you find an a different book? The very first equation in the solution seems to be treating *I* as if it were going through $X$ or $R$. But it isn't. It's going through the potentiometer wire. A huge blunder, robbing one of all confidence in the book.

Comment: Actually if you google the question, all the websites solve using same method. But I was doubtful.

Comment: The data enable one to get this equation: $$\frac{68.5}{58.3}=\frac{X(r+10)}{(r+X)10}.$$ $r$ is the internal resistance of the lower cell – which you don't know!

Comment: Thank you man..